# Camunda experssion access to extensionElements

Tags: expression, camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin, camunda-spin

I am new in camunda and I want to write a expression and want access to `extensionElements` like `processInstaceId` and `formKey`.
how can I do this?
please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is formKey, but

in groovy script process instance - `execution`

in java you can take it like this:

```java
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.context.Context
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity;

ExecutionEntity execution=Context.getBpmnExecutionContext().getProcessInstance();
```